# Error Installed packages have unmet dependencies , error with the sources.list file

Tags: apt, software-sources

I am trying to update my computer, but I am getting the following error:

```
'Unknown Error:'<class 'SystemError'>'(E: opening etc/apt/sources.list-ifstream::(13:permission denied))'
```

[image: (screenshot)]

Please help me resolve this issue.

Comment: look at the error: 'permition denied'. it means you need to use `sudo` before your command

Comment: @MostafaAhangarha i have edited the post and added a screenshot link to it , could you please check it out, its actually on the desktop environment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot check the screenshot at the moment, but the answer is obvious. By  running a quick Google search, I found [the answer](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1390420) you may need. Run the following commands from terminal:

```
sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.old
sudo cat /etc/apt/sources.list.old | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Comment: @Cloe - Grammar Police , it seems to have worked  ,well what does the error really mean

Comment: Well the error meant that your sources.list was either very corrupted or just had outdated and wrong information. If the answer did work, please make sure to check that little green box and upvote so other users can see this ;)